# How to write a pop up window function?

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
    //....
    success: function() {
    },
```

On `success` I want to pop up a fixed height and width window. There is a closed single locates on the window right angle. I did as the following, but it doesn't work.

I add a `div` which has a class named `success-tip`. I add some style to it and hide it at first. Then I use the following:

```
$.ajax({
    //....
    success: function() {
        success();
        $('.success-tip').show();    
    },
```

It doesn't pop up. What do I need to do to my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by opening the console (F12) and see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({ dialogClass:'custom_dialog', width: 350, zIndex: 9999, height: 398, resizable: false, draggable: false,
    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up"},
    hide: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up"}
});
</script>

<div id="dialog"><img src="xyz.jpg" /></div>
```

Put your popup content inside

```
<div id="dialog">your content for popup</div>
```

Pop up using [jquery Ui](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Write this code inside your success Function